# Homotopy groups of the blow-ups and monotone symplectic manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I want to calculate the second homotopy group of the blow-up of the unit cotangent disk bundle of a closed surface $\Sigma$, i.e $\pi_2\left(D^*T\Sigma\#\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}\right).$ Actually, I want to understand whether these symplectic manifolds are monotone. If yes, I want to find a closed monotone Lagrangian submanifold in it.

Comment: Serj and Mike, sorry for the confusion by my previous wrong answer, it is uneditable, so I deleted it.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $X$ for the manifold in question (i.e. the symplectic blowup of the unit disc bundle in the cotangent bundle of a surface $\Sigma$).

If you're interested just in monotonicity, what's relevant isn't so much $\pi_2(X)$ as the image of $\pi_2(X)$ under the Hurewicz map to $H_2(X;\mathbb{Z})$, which is quite a bit simpler--it has rank either one or two (generated at most by the zero section and the exceptional sphere, depending on what $\Sigma$ is).  Now $\omega$ evaluates as zero on the zero section and is positive on the exceptional sphere, while the first Chern class is zero on the zero section and $1$ on the exceptional sphere.  Thus $[\omega]$ and $c_1$ are positively proportional as elements of $H^2\left(X;R\right)$,
so   $X$ is always monotone, regardless of $\Sigma$.

Regarding monotone Lagrangian submanifolds, the obvious candidate is the zero section $\Sigma$.  Since $\pi_1(\Sigma)\to \pi_1(X)$ is an isomorphism, all classes in the relative $\pi_2$ come from the absolute $\pi_2$, so since the ambient manifold is monotone it directly follows that $\Sigma$ is a monotone Lagrangian submanifold.

When $\Sigma$ is $S^2$, there's another interesting example of a monotone Lagrangian $L\subset D^*TS^2$ discussed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608356) of Albers and Frauenfelder.  If you carefully choose the size of the blowup (so that the proportionality constant on the exceptional sphere is the same as the monotonicity constant for $L$), then it should be possible to arrange for $L$ to lift to a monotone Lagrangian torus in the blowup.  (However for a generic size blowup this probably won't work.)

Comment: Thank you Mike. While struggling with monotonicity via $\pi_2$ I also realized that it actually depends only on  spherical homology classes. Thank you for the reference. I am familiar with this torus too. I just wanted to work with monotone Lagrangians that lie in the interior of a convex compact symplectic manifold. I think another candidate for $L$ is the Clifford torus inside a small 4-ball (seating in some Darboux chart) blown-up in the origin

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to comment, so here is a comment on Dmitri's answer:

I think that if $\Sigma$ is not $S^2$ $\pi_2$ is bigger than $\mathbb{Z}$. For $\mathbb{R}P^2$ it is $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and for others it is a free abelian group generated by elements in $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ (each of those elements gives a copy of $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ in the universal cover).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Of course, I can look on the universal cover of the blow-up, which has isomorphic higher homotopy groups.